# Testing DELETED Expected [204] but was [404]

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, web-testing

I've been struggling trying to find out why my DELETED test method gets a 404 Https error, what i'm thinking is that the url provided to the test method is not being recogniced. I have used Postman to test the method, but Postman does the Delete Request [successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeuqK.png).

Can I get some help figuring this out?

**Test**

```
@Test
void remove() throws Exception {
    Long id = 35L;
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/fch-fiscal/usuarios/delete/{id}", id)).
    andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNoContent());
}
```

**Controller**

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> remove(@PathVariable("id") Long id) { // Elimina un usuario ingresado
    Optional<Usuario> o = service.findById(id);

    if (o.isPresent()) {
        service.remove(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build(); // 204
    }
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
%TESTC  1 v2
%TSTTREE2,mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest,true,1,false,1,UsuarioControllerTest,,[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest]
%TSTTREE3,remove(mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest),false,1,false,2,remove(),,[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest]/[method:remove()]
%TESTS  3,remove(mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest)

%FAILED 3,remove(mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest)
%TRACES 
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<204> but was:<404>
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:637)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:214)
        at mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest.remove(UsuarioControllerTest.java:72)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

%TRACEE 
%TESTE  3,remove(mx.com.ficachi.master.login.controllers.UsuarioControllerTest)

%RUNTIME6643
```

I've seen another questions and try to guide myself with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370472/how-to-test-delete-put-get-single-object-requests-in-spring-boot), but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a user with ID 35?

Comment: Yeah, i have user with id 35